# AngularJS ng-disable turn off all elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have next code:

```
<body ng-app="vote">
    <div>
        <div class="vote">
            <button ng-disabled="this.isDisabled" voteplus>+</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="vote">
            <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" voteplus>+</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="vote">
            <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" voteplus>+</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="vote">
            <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" voteplus>+</button>
        </div>  
        <div class="vote">
            <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" voteplus>+</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

and directive:

```
angular.module('vote', [])

.directive('voteplus', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                scope.isDisabled = true;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It's works, but it disables all elements on page, i need only current. What should i to improve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create new scope for the directive:

```
.directive('voteplus', function() {
    return {
        scope: true, // <-- add this
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                scope.isDisabled = true;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

With `scope: true` you are telling directive to create a new child scope (which inherits prototypically from the base one). In this case `scope.isDisabled = true` will only alter local child flag.